# Discrepancy in Variable names in the ANT built JAR

Tags: java, ant

I have built a JAR file using ANT 1.6.5 version. When i decompile the .class files into .java files, i can see the discrepancy in the variable names between the .java file and the decompiled .class file as shown below:

```
    String strFtpScriptName = null;                 Object obj = null;
    String strMailScriptName = null;                Object obj1 = null;
    boolean blnStatus = false;                      boolean flag = false;
    public void initialise(String strExtractName)   public void initialise(String s)
    String strFtpScriptName;                    String s1;
```

The left column is as in the original java file. The right column is the decompiled .class file. I have tried different ant versions. But still getting the same as above.

Anyone have any idea why the discrepancy in the variable names?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the source with `debuglevel="vars"` in the `javac` task.

`vars` will keep the variable names. You can also add `lines` will maintain the line numbers

You can have a look at [`javac`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) to see other options

Comment: Thanks for the reply Craig. I tried the above but haven't worked.